# How can I define scope in this case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 models such as `User` and `Uniquecode`
I'm using the gem called `acts_as_paranoid` which enables logical deletion. 
Basically, User has the column called 'deleted_at' and datetime will be set in that when User was deleted.

I defined this in Uniquecode model

```
scope :recent, lambda { |n = 10| includes(:user).order("users.last_active_at DESC").limit(n) }
```

However this code fetch all the users including the users deleted with logical deletion.
Those users whom deleted with logical deletion, has timestamp in the column of 'deleted_at'.

How can I ignore these people and fetch only the active users with this condition?
How can I code it in different way?

- 10 records at a time
- has to be sorted by the column 'last_active_at' in Users table. I want latest 10 records.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you?

```
scope :recent, lambda { |n = 10| includes(:user).where('users.deleted_at', nil).order("users.last_active_at DESC").limit(n) }
```

Comment: Thanks!! It looks almost there:) your code fetch only the deleted users. I want the opposite:)

Comment: Funny - what is in the deleted_at column?  Is it null if the user is not deleted?

Comment: Yes this is really funny. it does opposite.Yes there is timestamp in 'deleted_at' column of the deleted user.

Comment: Can you post the SQL? (do a to_sql on the end of the method call)

Comment: How about if you change the `where` statement to say `where('users.deleted_at = ?', nil)` or `where('users.deleted_at' => nil)`?  Not sure which syntax (if any) is correct in this case.

Comment: Nice!  Please accept @Swards' answer as he was conceptually correct.

Comment: I'd love to know how the sql was different.

Comment: My syntax was off, should have been where(users: {deleted_at: nil}})